# Using maven to turn TwelveMonkeys from Git into a Eclipse java project?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I've imported TwelveMonkeys into eclipse from git https clone, https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys.  And I would like to convert it into a java project, so I can build the jars.  After search, running "mvn eclipse:eclipse" in project root directory should do the trick!?  But I got this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: Metadata 3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) @ imageio-metadata >>>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Twelvemonkeys ..................................... SUCCESS [22.594s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: Common ........................... SUCCESS [0.022s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: Common :: Language support ....... SUCCESS [0.042s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: Common :: IO ..................... SUCCESS [0.048s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: Common :: Image .................. SUCCESS [0.051s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: Servlet .......................... SUCCESS [0.100s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO .......................... SUCCESS [0.025s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: Core .................. SUCCESS [0.038s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: Metadata .............. FAILURE [0.032s]
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: ICO plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: ICNS plugin ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: IFF plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: JPEG plugin ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: PDF plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: PICT plugin ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: PSD plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: Thumbs.db plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: TIFF plugin ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: Batik Plugin .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: JMagick Plugin ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] TwelveMonkeys :: ImageIO :: reference test cases .. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.971s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 29 12:26:42 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project imageio-metadata: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.twelvemonkeys
.imageio:imageio-metadata:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:ima
geio-core:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT, com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio-core:jar:tests:3.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.twelvemon
keys.imageio:imageio-core:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT in http://10.1.132.75:8888/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the loc
al repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ecvision.release has elapsed or updates a
re forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I haven't use Eclipse in a while but I guess in the recent versions, you can import a Maven project straight from the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `mvn clean install` first to package and install the jars in you local repository  and then `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will work.

The error message is explicit : it cannot find the `imageio-core:jar` dependency, cause you haven't install it yet.

Comment: Thanks Matt, the command **mvn clean install** is great.  I think it's a must-run cmd for all maven projects imported by eclipse.